# How to fix xcode editor from being all jittery and splitting lines of code?

Tags: xcode

Everything is default with my editor, but for some reason as I move around, edit lines, or it highlights stuff, it chops up the code in the editor till the point I can't even read it at times, or even be able to select the correct line. Anyone have a solution to fix this? I'm currently on xCode Version 7.2 (7C68)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart Xcode ?

Comment: I have, it does not stop it. If I scroll the code out of sight and bring it back, the screen will redraw it. Somedays xcode is really bad, rest of time it's alright. I have searched and search for a solution for a while now.

Comment: I would say your machine is on the blink.

Comment: I would agree if it was system wide (e.g memory issue), but its not. It's only related to a single application, xcode.

Comment: This is not a user fault - it is yet another Apple bug. Deleting Derived Data fixed it temporarily for me. No point posting how to delete derived data as Apple just change this at their whim. You're better off doing a SO search. It would be impossible to develop for iOS without StackOverflow.